# How to check ContentNote settings

Tags: managed-package, contentnote

I am working on managed package, it works fine and everybody is happy. In latest version I've added one trigger that works with ContentNote sObject.

Issue is that when I try to install it to the instance where ContentNotes are disabled I receives error:

> entity is not api accessible entity name contentnote

Question: how to check this in test class? It is not required to use this functionality if it is not configured. Who had such experience?

Answer (score 1):

You could write an extension package to handle the additional object. Or I suppose you could have a post-install step that guides the user to click a button that installs a trigger (e.g. Declarative Rollups can dynamically deploy triggers for whichever objects you put a realtime rollup on). In the latter case though the trigger won't deploy on Professional Edition.